# Why does Windows 7 Compatibility Mode have Windows 7 as an option?

Tags: windows-7

While resolving a problem with an addon for Visual Studio it was recommended that we start Visual Studio in Compatibility Mode with the option set to 'Windows 7'.

So first off.. the fact that Windows 7 is an option in Windows 7 is very strange to me.  But even weird this did solve the problem?!?

Can someone explain what setting compatibility to Windows 7 does.. in Windows 7?

Comment: Windows 7, or Windows 7 SP1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's giving you the option of simulating Windows 7 instead of Windows 7 SP1.  This option is not present if SP1 isn't installed.

Comment: Oh duh.. that makes so much sense.  Thanks very much :)